# How to sign in to a service using PHP

Tags: post, methods, registration

I want to sign in to a service (site) using PHP (without using its API)
If the service login was with a  and the method is 'GET', I would use

Service.com/signin.php?username=xxxx&password=xxxx

Now, the  has a POST method how can I do so??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a POST request using PHP's [cURL](http://php.net/curl) functions.

The relevant options are:

- CURLOPT_POST
- CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS